# Assistance needed install UCT IPTV AS (UCT Advanced IPtv)

Tags: ubuntu, voip, iptv

My IMS system have 6 component :

- P-CSCF
- S-CSCF
- I-CSCF
- HSS
- Media Broadcast Server
- UCT IPTV (UCT Advanced IPtv) as server

Each component run in each IP. But I can’t install the last component UCT IPTV AS (UCT Advanced IPtv) as server. I found it in sourceforge.net /projects/uctimsclient.berlios /files/ . I have tried many times to install, but it seems like a deadlock.

This UCT IPTV AS was build in Ubuntu 8.04 with `libosip 2.2.3`, `libexosip 2.2.3`, `libosip-dev`, `libexosip-dev`. Now Ubuntu version is 14.04, so I can't install it.

I have been doing this project last 8 months. UCT IPTV AS is a keynote for my final thesis.

When i install from uctiptv_advanced1.0.0.deb file, it's prompt:
*

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uctiptvas:
 uctiptvas depends on libosip2-2 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libosip2-2 is not installed.
 uctiptvas depends on libexosip2-4 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libexosip2-4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package uctiptvas (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 uctiptvas
```

*
i can found [libosip2-2.2.2.tar.gz][1] and [libeXosip2-2.2.3.tar.gz](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/exosip/) but cant install LibeXosip in Ubuntu 14.04. It's prompt error:

```
    checking ortp/ortp.h usability... no
checking ortp/ortp.h presence... no
checking for ortp/ortp.h... no
configure: error: oRTP library not installed. Please install or use --disable-josua
```

Continually, i install oRTP but it's seem ERROR again.

```
    stun.c: In function 'stunSendTest':
stun.c:1895:9: error: variable 'discard' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
    bool discard=false;
         ^
stun.c: In function 'stunNatType':
stun.c:2070:17: error: variable 'testIchangedAddr' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
    StunAddress4 testIchangedAddr;
                 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [stun.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/iptv/Desktop/ortp-0.11.0/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/iptv/Desktop/ortp-0.11.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/iptv/Desktop/ortp-0.11.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now i don't know what to do ..... help me please

Comment: More details would be super awesome - for example how you're attempting to build it and *specific* error messages

Comment: Actually, i'm working in Ubuntu 14.04. I have source of UCT IPTV AS with .deb file and tar.gz. ( download link in my above post)

Comment: And what error messages if you're compiling from source? 'I can't install it' tells us nothing at all.

Comment: many thank Journeyman Geek, i will update totally soon. just a few info i recenttly add in my above post

Comment: i was add some error about my project. i hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Reopened. *This* is the sort of information that would help someone solve this issue.